# install grails plugin image tools 1.0.5

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have to work with an existing grails project , using grails version 2.0.4
when i tried to run the project i had an error with the grails plugin "image-tools"

> Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
>   - org.grails.plugins:image-tools:1.0.5

in BuildConfig.groovy i have:

```
 plugins {
   ...
    compile ':image-tools:1.0.5'
   ...
}
```

application.properties:

```
 plugins.image-tools=1.0.5
```

so i tried to reinstall the plugin  but i always get this error:

```
| Environment set to development.....
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-collections/commons-collections/ivy-3.1.xml
  -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.1.jar
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-collections/commons-collections/bundles/commons-collections-3.1.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-collections-3.1.xml
  -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-collections-3.1.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-collections-3.1.xml
  -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-collections-3.1.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-collections-3.1.xml
  -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-collections-3.1.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/plugins/commons-collections-3.1.jar
==== image-tools plugin install resolver: tried
  -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/commons-collections-3.1.jar
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/grails-commons-collections-3.1.jar
    module not found: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-codec/commons-codec/ivy-1.3.xml
  -- artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3!commons-codec.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.3.jar
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-codec/commons-codec/bundles/commons-codec-1.3.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-codec-1.3.xml
  -- artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3!commons-codec.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-codec-1.3.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-codec-1.3.xml
  -- artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3!commons-codec.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-codec-1.3.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-codec-1.3.xml
  -- artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3!commons-codec.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-codec-1.3.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  -- artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3!commons-codec.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/plugins/commons-codec-1.3.jar
==== image-tools plugin install resolver: tried
  -- artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3!commons-codec.jar:
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/commons-codec-1.3.jar
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/grails-commons-codec-1.3.jar
    module not found: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/ivy-1.8.0.xml
  -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/bundles/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.xml
  -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.xml
  -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.xml
  -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/plugins/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
==== image-tools plugin install resolver: tried
  -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/grails-commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
    module not found: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-lang/commons-lang/ivy-2.4.xml
  -- artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.4.jar
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/lib/commons-lang/commons-lang/bundles/commons-lang-2.4.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-lang-2.4.xml
  -- artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/src/libs/commons-lang-2.4.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-lang-2.4.xml
  -- artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/dist/commons-lang-2.4.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-lang-2.4.xml
  -- artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.grails/2.0.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-lang-2.4.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  -- artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar:
  /home/proxymit/.gvm/grails/2.0.4/plugins/commons-lang-2.4.jar
==== image-tools plugin install resolver: tried
  -- artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar:
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/commons-lang-2.4.jar
  /home/proxymit/grails-imagetools-master/grails-commons-lang-2.4.jar
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1: not found
    :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3: not found
    :: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0: not found
    :: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4: not found
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Could not resolve all dependencies for plugin image-tools
```

Comment: First thing defining the plugin in `application.properties` is not needed. Since this is Grails 2.x the buildConfig is enough. Post your full buidconfig.groovy also.

Comment: This plugin version exists? http://grails.org/plugin/image-tools

Comment: @SérgioMichels, looks like that version exists on Github but not the Grails repo: https://github.com/ricardojmendez/grails-imagetools/commits/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally it works, here's how I did:

i downloaded the plugin zip from : https://github.com/ricardojmendez/grails-imagetools
then i extact it

```
cd (plugin directory)
grails upgrade
grails create-plugin ImageTools
grails package-plugin
cd (to the project using the plugin)
grails install-plugin (path to created plugin)
```

then i commented the other installed plugin in buildConfig.groovy and application.properties

then i instaleld the plugin from the genereted .zip

and finally i uncommented other plugin and run-app

Comment: Just a note: install-plugin is deprecated in Grails 2.x, you can do: `grails package-plugin` to install in a local maven repository, and then use the `BuildConfig.groovy` way of declaring the plugin. Also you may raise a issue in the github to see if this version should be available in grails.org.